# Boost Asio tcp::resolver: service not found

Tags: c++, boost, service, boost-asio, resolver

I'm trying to create an HTTP client using Boost Asio. I copied the sync client example from asio, compile, then run. Unfortunately, on my logs, it shows Service not found. When I traced the code, I found it that it is thrown from the following code:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
// Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
//->if i removed the http, it has no error
tcp::resolver::query query("host.com", "http");
//->This part throws the service not found
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::resolver::iterator end;
```

Can anybody explain why it is throwing service not found or on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This means the OS does not know which port number corresponds to the TCP service with the name "http".

On a unix-like OS, this would mean the line `http 80/tcp` is missing from `/etc/services`, I am able to reproduce the error on Linux by commenting that line out.

If the OS cannot be configured to use services, you may use any service `""` in the resolver, and specify the port number explicitly when creating the endpoint object for the connect call:

```
tcp::endpoint connectionEndpoint(endpoint_iterator->address(), 80);
boost::system::error_code ec;
socket.connect(connectionEndpoint, ec);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Will try this out when I get back to work. Thanks.

Comment: You can also give the port number as a string e.g. query("host.com", "80")